# Instagram API Comments Created using Python (ERROR: AttributeError)

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, instagram, instagram-api

I trying out Instagram API using python and I am new to it. Hope you could take a look at it and help me out.

I am wondering how to collect the date & time from users that have commented for each media id.

I have tried using 'created_time' but it did not manage to collect anything. 
Any ideas how to troubleshoot it? Or is there something wrong with my code? I manage to print out username & their comments though.

Here is my code:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

import re


access_token = "XXX"
client_secret = "XXX"

api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(user_id="476132155")

while next_:
    more_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(with_next_url=next_)
    recent_media.extend(more_media)

for media in recent_media:
    try:
        comments = api.media_comments(media.id)

        for i in comments:
            print i.created_time

    except (UnicodeEncodeError):
        pass
```

AttributeError: 'Comment' object has no attribute 'created_time'

Comment: Well, you're catching and ignoring the errors, so there's no way to tell what's going on. Don't do that. (And there's no point in catching SyntaxError anyway, as that is a compile-time exception not a run-time one, so can never be caught.)

Comment: I tried print out media.created_time. It works but not for i.created_time. Maybe I shall take your advice and try it out. Thanks!

Comment: AttributeError: 'Comment' object has no attribute 'created_time'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Instagram is not very consistent in their API. The creation time of a media object is called `created_time`, but for a comment it is `created_at`.

Also note there's no need to request the comments separately: they are already available for each media object, in `media.comments`.